# PySpark: Which DataFrame methods accept another DataFrame as a parameter?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I know that `df1.join(df2)` is an example of a `DataFrame`method that accepts another `DataFrame`. I'm not in front of my `JupyterLab Notebook` to exhaustively check, but does anyone know (or where to find) the list of all `DataFrame` methods that accept another `DataFrame`? I suspect there are only a handful.

**REASON**: I want to `comparatively` iterate over two `DataFrame`s without `join()`ing them. (The nature of the `comparison` is yet to be determined). So my first step is answering the above question, and then study what those methods do.

**PS**: I know I may be able to concoct something using `df.foreach(fn)`, but I'll start with answering the above question first.

**EDIT**: A subtle sub-quesrion here is, `Without joining them, how can one iterate over two DataFrames using the newer structured DataFrame API, if possible? Is something implemented in that newer API that allows this?` One answerer below delightfully picked up on the subtlety, and offered one alternative approach using `RDD`s.

Thanks to all in advance.

Comment: Why not browser the API docs of data frame? There you'll find the list of all methods.

Comment: The methods which accept a dataframe are related to SQL set operators : UNION, INTERSECT, SUBTRACT, JOIN. The same operators exists as dataframe methods. You can find them in the doc by looking for `(other)` partern.

Comment: @Steven Thank you. Why don't you add this as an Answer and I'll UpVote it (as I have another answer below). The methods you named answered the question, and mentioning the `other` pattern will be useful to other searchers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check pyspark.sql module documentation here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame (Make sure you are watching an actual version for you)

I think there isn't any option to iterate over DF and compare them without join.
But you can try to cast your DF to RDD ([Documenation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD)) and then zip them and use functions like map, filter etc.

Let'me show your a small example:

```
df1 = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    Row(value = 1),
    Row(value = 2),
    Row(value = 3)
])

df2 = spark_session.createDataFrame([
    Row(value = 1),
    Row(value = 22),
    Row(value = 33)
])

rdd1 = df1.rdd
rdd2 = df2.rdd

zippedRdd = rdd1.zip(rdd2)

filterRdd = zippedRdd.filter(lambda tuple_of_rows: tuple_of_rows[0][0] == tuple_of_rows[1][0])
```

In this example we just create 2 dataframes with one column then cast them to rdd(You can think about [RDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#resilient-distributed-datasets-rdds) as distributed collection of [Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row)).

So zippedRdd in this example is RDD of tuple of two Rows and tuple_of_rows[0][0] means get me first element of Row of first RDD.

Also it's importand to understand 2 things about RDD:

1. RDD is low-level Spark API and you can't get optimization like in Structured API(DataFrame API)
2. You might have a performance issues while using RDD, because spark will serialize and deserialize data between JVM process and Python daemon proccess

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I suspected that `iteration` & `comparison` might not be possible without resorting to RDDs, and is why I mentioned the use-case parenthetically; which you picked up on and offered an example. I was concerned with relative `RDD` performance degradation as compared to `DataFrames` that you mentioned. It's the core reason why I posted this question. `=:)` `UpVoted` and `Marked`.